# nested ng-repeat in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I have a following code where I need to extract value of `a` at all the occurrence . What I have to do is use `<span ng-repeat="x in carname">` as parent element, which I dont want to. How can I get value of `a` directly.

**P.S.:** `$scope.carname` can not be moderated

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.carname = [
    [{
      "a": 1
    }],
    [{
      "a": 2
    }],
    [{
      "a": 3
    }],
    [{
      "a": 4
    }]
  ];
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <span ng-repeat="x in carname">
    <h1 ng-repeat="y in x">{{y.a}}</h1>
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: there will be only `a` property or more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have this structure then you can do like this

```
<span ng-repeat="x in carname">
    <h1>{{x[0].a}}</h1>
 </span>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.carname =[
        [{"a":1}],
        [{"a":2}],
        [{"a":3}],
        [{"a":4}]
    ];
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="cn in carname">
    {{cn[0].a}}
  </div>
</div>
```

You can pretty much run one loop over the `carname` array, and since each element in that array is another array with just one element, get the first item `cn[0]` and then find the value by key, which is `a`.

And of course you can always use a nested `ng-repeat` or transform the data to some other format that makes it even easier to display.